Left and right movement script not working
I'm creating a really simple 2d platformer game, and I'm creating a super basic enemy that detects if there is a wall in front of it, and it there is, it changes directions. But when I start the game, after 1 second for the 1st raycast, the enemy stops moving.
I tried A LOT of different things, I think this is like 4th version of the script.
private enum Moving 
{
   MovingToRight,
   MovingToLeft,
   Idle
}

private void Update()
{
    timer += Time.deltaTime;

    if (timer > 1f) 
    {
        Debug.Log("Raycast fired!");
        raycastHitLeft = Physics2D.Raycast(transform.position, new Vector3(-9, -3.5f, 0), 2);
        raycastHitRight = Physics2D.Raycast(transform.position, new Vector3(9, -3.5f, 0), 2);
        timer = 0;
    }

    if (raycastHitRight.collider != null)
    {
        Debug.Log("Right Raycast Not Hitting Anything, Should Move!");
        moving = Moving.MovingToRight;
    }
    else 
    {
        moving = Moving.Idle;
    }
    
    if (raycastHitLeft.collider != null)
    {
        Debug.Log("Left Raycast Not Hitting Anything, Should Move!");
        moving = Moving.MovingToLeft;
    }
    else
    {
        moving = Moving.Idle;
    }

    while (moving == Moving.MovingToRight && moving != Moving.MovingToLeft)
    {
        transform.position += new Vector3(1, 0, 0) * Time.deltaTime;
        return;
    }

    while (moving == Moving.MovingToLeft && moving != Moving.MovingToRight)
    {
        transform.position += new Vector3(-1, 0, 0) * Time.deltaTime;
        return;
    }

    while (moving == Moving.MovingToRight && moving == Moving.MovingToLeft)
    {
        //If both true, move to right
        transform.position += new Vector3(1, 0, 0) * Time.deltaTime;
        return;
    }
}


debug my friend, debug.. add messages, show whats happening, what the values are.. usually this clears up why you cant see why its doing something

@BugFinder I removed most of the Debug.Log-s when writeing this, otherwise there are in every if

Hi @Svak, is there any particular reason why you are using while loops for the "moving" (i.e transform.position) part? I see that you are doing return in the body, meaning the while loop will not run for more than one iteration.

are the raycasts supposed to be going diagonally downwards?

Surely, your character stops moving because you set moving to Idle when a collision is detected on either side.

@Ruzihm no, i fixed it when i used Debug.DrawRay, but still not working

It looks like you have mixed up your logic for the wall detection.
To check for collision, you are using Physics2D.Raycast, which returns a Physics2D.Raycast.
In your code, you are doing:
raycastHitLeft = Physics2D.Raycast(transform.position, new Vector3(-9, -3.5f, 0), 2);
raycastHitRight = Physics2D.Raycast(transform.position, new Vector3(9, -3.5f, 0), 2);

// Your other code

if (raycastHitRight.collider != null)
{
    Debug.Log("Right Raycast Not Hitting Anything, Should Move!");
    moving = Moving.MovingToRight;
}
else 
{
    moving = Moving.Idle;
}

According to documentation of RaycastHit2D.collider,

The collider hit by the ray.
Note that some functions that return a single RaycastHit2D will leave the collider as NULL which indicates nothing hit

Hence, when raycastHitRight.collider != null, it means that the raycast has collided with something. This is contradicting your debugging message of "Right Raycast Not Hitting Anything, Should Move!". What you should do is to invert the logic, simply by doing raycastHitRight.collider == null. The same can be said for raycastHitLeft.
The above should resolve the issue of the enemy not moving after 1 second. After that, if you find that the direction change is not correct, you should attempt to debug and fix it on your own, or you can ask as another question.

Additionally, you can improve the second part of your script:
while (moving == Moving.MovingToRight && moving != Moving.MovingToLeft)
{
    transform.position += new Vector3(1, 0, 0) * Time.deltaTime;
    return;
}

while (moving == Moving.MovingToLeft && moving != Moving.MovingToRight)
{
    transform.position += new Vector3(-1, 0, 0) * Time.deltaTime;
    return;
}

while (moving == Moving.MovingToRight && moving == Moving.MovingToLeft)
{
    //If both true, move to right
    transform.position += new Vector3(1, 0, 0) * Time.deltaTime;
    return;
}

Firstly, it is redundant to use while loops in this case as you are doing return in the loops' body. This means that the loop will never run more than once. Hence, you can use if conditions instead.
Secondly, you only have 2 variations of "action" to take: either "move left" or "move right". Therefore, you can actually simply to 2 if conditions instead of the original 3 conditions.
To elaborate, moving is an enum and cannot possibly be both Moving.MovingToRight and Moving.MovingToLeft at the same time. Hence, we actually just need to check for == for the desired direction.
Improving on the 2 points mentioned above, you can improve so that it looks like this:
if (moving == Moving.MovingToLeft)
{
    transform.position += new Vector3(-1, 0, 0) * Time.deltaTime;
    return;
}

if (moving == Moving.MovingToRight)
{
    transform.position += new Vector3(1, 0, 0) * Time.deltaTime;
    return;
}


Surely if the right raycast detects a hit, moving should be set to MovingToLeft, no? Is there a situation where moving should be set to Idle? The asker never seemed to suggest anything like that in their description of the desired outcome. In moving == Moving.MovingToLeft && moving != Moving.MovingToRight what is the purpose of && moving != Moving.MovingToRight?

Also, is there a reason to have the raycasts going diagonally downwards? If it's to detect multiple heights of obstacles, then would it not be better to use a Box/Circle/CapsuleCast or multiple horizontal raycasts of the same distance? That would be more visually consistent in how close the enemy gets to the obstacle before the enemy turns around

@Ruzihm I'm unsure of OP's use case for raycasting diagonally, nor with the OP's choice to move left when right raycast detects a hit. Since OP did not state the desired outcome, I had followed the logic in the original code. In OP's question, the issue faced was that the "enemy stops moving". Hence, we should fix it to get it to start moving first. Afterwards, OP can fix the direction change if found to be facing the wrong direction, or ask for help in a separate question.

You are right! Now that you brought it up, && moving != Moving.MovingToRight is actually not needed. I shall modify my answer accordingly.
